# How write a SQL query in HQL language?

Tags: sql, hql, inner-join

I'm trying to write this:

```
select s.to_date 'Fecha Fin', concat(e.first_name, " ", e.last_name) as 'Full Name', t.title as 'Title', s.salary as 'Salary'
from dept_emp as d
join employees as e on d.emp_no = e.emp_no
join salaries s on s.emp_no = e.emp_no
join titles t on t.emp_no = e.emp_no
where d.dept_no = "d007"
order by e.emp_no, s.to_date desc;
```

on HQL language. This is what I wrote:

```
session.createQuery("select s.to_date, concat(e.first_name,'', e.last_name) as FullName, t.title as Title, s.salary as Salary
from Department as d
inner join Employees as e where d.emp_no = e.emp_no  
inner join Salaries s where s.emp_no = e.emp_no
inner join Titles t where t.emp_no = e.emp_no
where s.to_date = '9999-01-01' 
AND d.dept_no = 'd007' 
order by e.emp_no, s.to_date desc") as Department
```

But I'm having this error:

```
0 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.hql.PARSER  - line 10:57: unexpected token: inner
```

I know that the syntax error is not the only error, but I could not find any answer for this problem.

Any idea? 
thanks.

Comment: Perhaps its because you forgot the keyword 'as' after Salaries and Titles

Comment: Thanks! But it's not that .. I suppose That " as " can be obviated in HQL ... I prove that and the error persist.

Comment: Then ist must be the `as`  in `Department as d` ;-) It's a long time since worked with hibernate. And I can remember there was an issue with 'as'. But I don't know exactly where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not valid HQL. There is only one where clause allowed. And you don't tell Hibernate how to join your entities in the query. You tell Hibernate how to join your entities when you map them.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html

It should look more like this, where the joined entities are property names, not the table names. For example your Department entities would have a collection of type `Employee` called `employees`.

```
session.createQuery("select s.to_date, " + 
    " concat(e.first_name,'', e.last_name) as FullName, " + 
    " t.title as Title, s.salary as Salary " +
    " from Department as d " + 
    " inner join d.employees as e " +
    " inner join e.salary as s " +
    " inner join e.title t " +
    " where s.to_date = '9999-01-01' " + 
    " AND d.dept_no = 'd007' " +
    " order by e.emp_no, s.to_date desc");
```